# En java por mas que le ponga los retornos boleanos me dice que tiene que retornar un boleano

Tags: java, booleano

Estoy viendo Java en la Universidad y me dan este ejercicio para realizar "Escribir un metodo static boolean esSinRepetidos(String s) que dada una cadena, devuelve true si no hay letras repetidas en la cadena"
No me deja ejecutar ya que me salta un error que me dice que este método debe retornar un boleano

```
static boolean esSinRepetidos (String cad){
    for (int i=0; i<=cad.length(); i++){
        for (int j=1; j<=cad.length()-1; i++){
            if (cad.charAt(i)== cad.charAt(j)){
                return false;
            }
            else{
                return true;}   
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

el problema es debido a que en tu código el return no cubre todos los casos.

¿A que me refiero? Solo estas haciendo "return" si tu código entra al for(){}. Si por alguna razón no entra al for la función no podría regresarte algún valor, es por esto que te marca el error de que debe regresar un bool.

Adicionalmente tu código tiene mal lógica:

- En ambos ciclos sumas 1 a la variable i.
- Tu código regresará true con que el primer ciclo sea diferente en la comparación.
- Le falta una llave al final para cerrar la función

Siguiendo tu lógica, lo correcto sería algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
    static boolean esSinRepetidos (String cad){

        for (int i=0; i<=cad.length() -1; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<=cad.length() -1; j++){
                if(i != j){
                    System.out.println("comparando: " + cad.charAt(i) + " con: " + cad.charAt(j));
                    if (cad.charAt(i)== cad.charAt(j)){
                        //Hay letras repetidas? en ese caso regresa false, pues si las hay
                        return false;
                    }  
                }
            }
        }
        //si llega a este punto quiere decir que no hay repetidas
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Hola Miguel! Muchas gracias, me podrías explicar porqué pusiste que i!=j y no iniciaste j en 1?

Comment: @LoreDenhoff el i!=j es para que el ciclo no llegue a comparar la misma letra ya que en algún punto ambas variables tendrán el mismo valor y lo intentará comparar  (dando como resultado siempre false).

Lo de la variable j no iniciada en 1 es debido a que el index comienza en 0. Si lo inicializas en 1 tu ciclo no estará revisando la primera letra de tu string en cada ciclo de i :).

De hecho lo más recomendable en este caso sería j = i + 1. Esto para que tu segundo ciclo no haga comparaciones que ya hiciste con anterioridad.

Espero haberte ayudado. ¡Saludos!

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la explicación!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Como te menciono Miguel, tu error era en que tu codigo no cubria todos los casos..
Aqui  te dejo otra opcion para poder realizarlo:

```
static boolean esSinRepetidos(String cad) {
        boolean bandera = false;
        char[] letras = cad.toCharArray();
        HashMap map = new HashMap();
        for (char letra : letras) {
            map.put(letra, "");
        }

        //Si el mapa tiene la misma longitud de la cadena no tiene repetidos
        if (map.size() == cad.length()) {
            bandera = true;
        }

        return bandera;
    }
```

Comment: Hola! Te agradezco, pero no estamos trabajando con banderas y no estaría entendiendo qué es map, igual gracias

Answer (score 2):

El error puede deberse a que no se considera el caso de que la cadena este vacía, es decir, si la longitud de la cadena es 0 entonces nunca se va a ejecutar el ciclo for, debido a esto tampoco se van a ejecutar los return, además, como buena práctica se recomienda que las funciones solo contengan un return.

Dejo mi respuesta y espero resuelva tu duda:

```
public static boolean esSinRepetidos(String cad){
    boolean state = false; //Bandera que dice si es que hay o no algun caracter repetido
    int size = cad.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for(int j = i + 1; j < size; j++){
            if(cad.charAt(i) == cad.charAt(j)){ //Comparas el caracter i con los caracteres siguientes a i 
                state = true; //Si encuentras un caracter igual, cambia el estado de la bandera
                break; //Rompes el segundo ciclo
            }
        }
        if(state)
            break; //Si ya encontraste un caracter igual, rompes el primer ciclo 
    }
    return state; //Regresas el booleano
}
```

Comment: Gracia por tu aporte, no estamos trabajando con bandera

Answer (score 1):

Asi es como deberias hacerlo:

```
static boolean esSinRepetidos (String cad){
    for (int i=0; i<=cad.length(); i++){
        for (int j=1; j<=cad.length()-1; i++){
            if (cad.charAt(i)== cad.charAt(j)){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Aunque yo llamaria al metodo 'tieneCaracteresRepetidos' (haciendo los cambios correspondientes en el algoritmo).

Comment: Hola! Me di cuenta del error de iniciar j en cero, lo modifiqué y aún así siempre me da falso

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así.

```
static boolean esSinRepetidos (String cad){
    for (int i=0; i<=cad.length(); i++){
        for (int j=1; j<=cad.length()-1; i++){
            if (cad.charAt(i)== cad.charAt(j)){
                return false;
            }
            else{
                return true;}   
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Así siempre retornará `false`

Answer (score 0):

Me he dado cuenta que ese tipo de errores, es porque Java quiere reducir el margen de fallo en el código. Podrías intentar haciendo lo siguiente:

```
static boolean esSinRepetidos (String cad){
   boolean b = false;
   for (int i=0; i<=cad.length(); i++){
      for (int j=1; j<=cad.length()-1; i++){
         if (cad.charAt(i)== cad.charAt(j)){
            b= false;
         }
         else{
            b= true;}   
      }
   }
   return b;
```

}

Así te aseguras que siempre tendrás un valor boleano de retorno.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte